# MVC4 changing dataobject when selecting item in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm fairly new to MVC and I'm not coming up with the right question to get my answer from Google, so here I am.

I have a dropdownlist box that holds a 'list' of addresses associated to a customer, on this page I want to be able to click on one of the addresses and use the selected 'id' to get the correct address model from a list to populate all the address fields and switch when a different address is selected.  Can this be done with binding or do I have to do a lot of 'manual' resetting of the values?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.CityState, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Location.City
                                            , Model.Carrier.Locations.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ID.ToString(), Text = x.CityState })
                                            , new { @rows = 6, @multiple = false, style = "width: 300px;", onchange = "onChangeLocationDDL(this)" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Address1, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Address1)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Address1)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Address2, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Address2)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Address2)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.City, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.City)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.City)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.State, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.State)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.State)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Zip, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Zip)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Zip)
                </div>
            </div>

        </td>
        <td valign="top">

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Country, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Country)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Country)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Latitude, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Latitude)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Latitude)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Longitude, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Longitude)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.Longitude)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.LocationType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.LocationType, (new CarrierDirectoryWeb.Models.LocationTypes()).ToSelectList())
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.LocationType)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedLocation.CarrierID)
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ok hitting the controller to update a part of the page here is how you could do it:

-create a partial view for your html that is responsible for displaying the address.

-have your original view call this partial and pass in the address model.

-create an action that will take an Id and return the PartialViewResult.

-pass onchange as an html attribute for your dropdown that will should be a one liner using jquery to call the action method and replace the div that contains the address.